# Serialize and deserialize a field according to another field value

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, jackson-databind

How can I serialize or deserialize a field, according to another field value within the same class?

In the following example, when serializing or deserializing `Packet` class, I would like that `type` field will determine *how* `payload` field will be serialized and deserialized.

PayloadType enum

```
public enum PayloadType {
    HTTP,
    HTTPS,
    FTP
}
```

Packet class

```
public class Packet {
    private final String payload;
    // This field should determine how "payload" field is serialized.
    private final PayloadType type;     
    private final Date creationTime;

@JsonCreator
public Packet(String payload, PayloadType type) {
    this.payload = payload;
    this.type = type;
    this.creationTime = new Date();
}

public String getPayload() {
    return this.payload;
}

public PayloadType getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public Date getCreationTime() {
    return this.creationTime;
}
```

Test

```
public class PacketTests {
@Test
public void packetSerialization_fromHttpType() throws JsonProcessingException {
    // Given
    ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
    String payload = "hello world";
    PayloadType type = PayloadType.HTTP;
    Packet packet = new Packet(payload, type);
    String json;

    // When
    json = jackson.writeValueAsString(packet);

    // Then
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Current output

```
{"payload":"hello world","type":"HTTP","creationTime":1542538836041}
```

Expected outputs

```
{"payload":"(http) hello world","type":"HTTP","creationTime":1542538836041}
{"payload":"(https) hello world","type":"HTTPS","creationTime":1542538836041}
{"payload":"X9hnahj83","type":"FTP","creationTime":1542538836041}
```

The `payload` of `FTP` is base64 string.

Comment: you need a [`custom seralizer`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) and a `custom deseralizer`

Comment: @guleryuz you right, but I didn't find any straightforward way to do it using custom serializer and deserializer.

Comment: a simpler way may be placing a new method in `Packet` class like `public String getPayloadLong() { return "(" + getType().name().toLowerCase() + ") " + getPayload(); }` then you will see a new field in json with name `payloadLong`. this way you do not need `custom (de)seralizer`s

Comment: @guleryuz the code I wrote was just an example, so, as another example, consider the `payload` for `FTP` type, to be string base 64 byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @  comment update the payload getter to return different output values

```
 public String getPayload() {
     return "(" + getType().name().toLowerCase() + ") " +  this.payload;
 }
```

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360094/serialize-and-deserialize-a-field-according-to-another-field-value/53362196#comment93599344_53360094) for @guleryu, I've also updated the expected result in the question (specifically for `FTP` type)

Comment: @Eido95 yoy can do it yourself , no?

Comment: As a workaround, indeed I can do it myself, however that's why I'm asking, if it's possible to do it using Jackson - maybe it's not.